# Problem creating dynamic views in fragment layout

Tags: java, android, view

im trying to set some checkbox dinamically into ona of my fragment layouts, but i cant get it. Need some help please, it is my first time working with fragments and im a bit lost.

Thanks all.

I post my code bellow:

MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "ResourceType"})
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout fragContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pasosLayout);
    LinearLayout pasosLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    pasosLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    pasosLayout.setId(12345);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(pasosLayout.getId(), TestFragment.newInstance("I 
am frag 1"), "someTag1").commit();


    fragContainer.addView(pasosLayout);

   }
 }
```

TestFragment.java:

```
   public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

   public static android.app.Fragment newInstance(String text) {

    TestFragment f = new TestFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("text", text);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {

    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFragText)).setText(getArguments().getString("text"));
    return v;
}
}
```

And the last, my fragment.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="200dp" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFragText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should add `addView(pasosLayout)` inside your `TestFragment ` class. From your Activity class, pass needed parameters, then add view to a Fragment's view hierarchy inside the `TestFragment ` class

Comment: Thank you, i will try this.

Comment: I don't see any checkbox anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `pasosLayout` to `fragContainer` after fragment transaction,

So first add that `pasosLayout` to `fragContainer`, also you should set layoutParams to your `pasosLayout`

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "ResourceType"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout fragContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pasosLayout);
        LinearLayout pasosLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                       ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        pasosLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        pasosLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        pasosLayout.setId(12345);


        fragContainer.addView(pasosLayout);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(pasosLayout.getId(), 
        TestFragment.newInstance("I am frag 1"), "someTag1").commit();

    }
}
```

Comment: Im going to test it, i need to understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add your views through fragments... just inflate your view, populate its data, and add it do the container directly.

```
View checkbox = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, fragContainer, false);
TextView text = checkbox.findViewById(R.id.tvFragText);
text.setText("My cool text");
fragContainer.addView(checkbox);
```

Comment: Ok! There are several ways to get the inflater, maybe you should use LayoutInflater.from(context)